# Finding curl of a scalar function?

Tags: vector-analysis

I am having some trouble with a problem on my calc 3 homework that asks me to compute curl(∇f). I'm confused because we are given a scalar function and my professor only taught how to compute curl with vector functions, by taking the cross product of ∇ and each vector component.

I was wondering if anyone would be able to provide some guidance about how to approach the problem... I thought curl could only be computed with vector functions?

f(x,y,z) = x^2y^3z

Comment: But ∇f is a vector! So just calculate the curl of this vector.

Comment: so take the gradient of f(x,y,z), then the curl of that?

Comment: exactly so  .....

Comment: thank you! much appreciated!!!

Comment: turned out to be (0,0,0)... is this a commonality for all scalars or just a coincidence for this one function?

Comment: It's a general theorem

Comment: good intuition! it's a commonality for all scalar functions, and is the "local" (= done with differentials) version of the fact that integrating the vector field ∇f around a loop gets you 0—which is in turn kind of like a higher-dimensional version of the fact that integrating the derivative of a function f(x) gets you the difference between the two endpoints (but here, the endpoints are the same, so you get 0). If you haven't already, you'll soon see how the curl is related to integrating a vector field around a loop :)

Comment: however, I just want to make sure: have you come to the wrong stackexchange by accident? This one is for the software/programming language Mathematica, which can indeed be used to compute curl and gradient, but given that your question seems to be about the math itself, I wonder if you made a one-key typo and meant to go to the mathematics stackexchange (which we see happen a lot here!)

Comment: thanks for the help! we've learned about vector fields and how curls related to then, but I was confused because we never applied anything we learned about the curl to a scalar function. makes sense now! and yes, I went to the wrong one... oops!